# C# - How do I remove a file from the recent documents list in word?

Tags: c#, windows, ms-word

Im trying to delete the Recent Document form the Recent menu in the MS Word, I tried delete the file in the RecentItems(in Explorer), but still my word shows the file in Recent Documents menu.

I found a solution to solve it using VB,
[VBA - How do I remove a file from the recent documents list in excel 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879334/vba-how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-recent-documents-list-in-excel-2007)

How can i achieve this in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use automation to do that.
There are quite a few steps you have to take to get programming :

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316384

- Add a reference to Microsoft Word Object Library.

To do this, follow these steps :
On the Project menu, click Add Reference.
On the COM tab, locate Microsoft Word Object Library, and then click Select.

- now you can get started :

with code like

```
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc"; /* \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark */ 

//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
```

oWord is the application object as in the VBA application.
The recent file list and everything should be there.

Comment: can you help me with how to use oWord.RecentFiles property to remove the particular file from RecentDocuments? @Philip Stuyck

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the entries in the registry from c#.

The key would be something like this:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Word\File MRU
```

For registry manipulation you can find lots of articles how to do that from C#.