# VBA macro create temporary file

Tags: vba, ms-word, recent-file-list

I am using a macro which creates temporary docx files that are then assembled into one.
I then delete the temporary files.
These files still show up in the Recent Files list, even though they no longer exist.
How can I prevent these temp files from being recognized by Word as a recent file?

Or is there a way to save the contents of the would-be temporary file in an array and then use this array to complete the final file? Meaning, the temp file does not ever actually exist.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879334/vba-how-do-i-remove-a-file-from-the-recent-documents-list-in-excel-2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fifth parameter of `Document.SaveAs` is `AddToRecentFiles`. Set that to False.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220734

You can create the temporary files, combine them into one, and then close them  without saving them.

Comment: Please note that the `Documents.Open` method has a similar parameter.